# XML node replace failure

Tags: java, xslt, nosql, xquery, marklogic

I try Corb to search and update node in large number of documents:

Sample input:

```
<hcmt xmlns="http://horn.thoery">
  <susceptible>X</susceptible>
  <reponsible>foresee–intervention</reponsible>
  <intend>Benefit Protagonist</intend>
  <justified>Goal Outwiegen</justified>
</hcmt>
```

Xquery:

```
(: let $resp   :=  "foresee–intervention" :)
 
let $docs :=    
  cts:search(doc(),
  cts:and-query((
  cts:collection-query("hcmt"),
  cts:path-range-query("/horn:hcmt/horn:responsible", "=", $resp)
        ))
    )
return
  for $doc in $docs
return
  xdmp:node-replace($doc/horn:hcmt/horn:responsible, "Foresee Intervention")
```

Expected output:

```
<hcmt xmlns="http://horn.thoery">
  <susceptible>X</susceptible>
  <reponsible>Foresee Intervention</reponsible>
  <intend>Benefit Protagonist</intend>
  <justified>Goal Outwiegen</justified>
</hcmt>
```

But node-replace didn’t happen in Corb and no error returns. Other queries work fine in Corb.  How can the node-replace work correctly in Corb?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you expecting xdmp:node-replace() to return the modified doc, or are you saying that when you go look at the doc it isn't modified?

Comment: You won't see the product of your change in that transaction. You will need to run another query reading the doc to see the change. Notice that the code example for `xdmp:node-replace()` function https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace uses a `;` between the call to perform the replace and the `fn:doc()` to verify the change.  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_24207

Comment: And you probably want to replace the `text()` of that element, not the element. `xdmp:node-replace($doc/horn:hcmt/horn:responsible/text(), text{"Foresee Intervention"})`

Comment: Thanks, @Mads Hansen. Other queries or node-replace transaction work fine in Corb. I try your `xdmp:node-replace($doc/horn:hcmt/horn:responsible/text(), text{"Foresee Intervention"})` in Corb. Still node-replace didn’t happen in Corb. The failure happens in Corb not in query console.

Comment: So, is it not modifying docs? And you are sure you are executing against the correct content DB?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure.

Comment: And same user? No chance that the user executing CoRB can’t see docs, and you see it processing records(not selecting 0)? I can’t think of many other reasons why it would behave different via CoRB/XCC vs QConsole

Comment: @Chris:  The special dash in `foresee–intervention` which the API fails to decode calls for attention. Odd as it may sound, the encoded `foresee%e2%80%93intervention` could be that `$resp`. Then `cts:path-range-query("/horn:hcmt/horn:responsible",  "=",  xdmp:url-decode($resp))` .  You give it a shot in CORB.

Comment: Fiona, Yes, that solves the node replace issue in Corb! Do you want to put the comment as Answer?  Is there any other efficient API to support a more readable query with example? I work with Java, and know some MarkLogic Java.

Comment: Ah, tricky. I didn't realize that it was an em-dash, not a regular dash. em-dash and curly quotes are an endless source of pain and confusion! (not just with MarkLogic APIs)

Comment: Mads:  I’d have to take it very much amiss if an enterprise database platform wouldn’t honor the more artistic punctuation than it’s often given credit for being.

Comment: Without seeing how the job is configured, it is difficult to guess as to where/how the character was getting mangled. However, if files are read with an incorrect character encoding, that multi-byte character can be read as two garbage characters. It is a common problem, and not an issue with MarkLogic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I create functions to reconcile the encoding matters. This not only mitigates potential API transaction failures but also is a requisite to validate & encode parameter or element/property/uri name.

> That said, a sample MarkLogic Java API implementation is:

1. Create a dynamic query construct in the filesystem, in my case, `product-query-option.xml` (use the query value directly: `Chooser–Option`)

```
<search xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <query>
        <and-query>
            <collection-constraint-query>
                <constraint-name>Collection</constraint-name>
                <uri>proto</uri>
            </collection-constraint-query>
            <range-constraint-query>
                <constraint-name>ProductType</constraint-name>
                <value>Chooser–Option</value>
            </range-constraint-query>
        </and-query>
    </query>
</search>
```

2. Deploy the persistent query options to modules database, in my case, `search-lexis.xml`, the options file is like:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
     <constraint name="Collection">
         <collection prefix=""/>
     </constraint>
     <constraint name="ProductType">
        <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1">
          <path-index xmlns:prod="schema://fc.fasset/product">/prod:requestProduct/prod:_metaData/prod:productType</path-index>
        </range>
     </constraint>
</options>
```

3. Follow on from [Dynamic Java Search](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144)

```
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/queryoption/product-query-option.xml");

        FileHandle fileHandle = new FileHandle(file);

        RawCombinedQueryDefinition rcqDef = queryMgr.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(fileHandle, queryOption);
```

- You can, assuredly, combine the query and the options as one handle in `QueryDefinition`.

4. Your original node-replace is translated as [Java Partial Update](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_46664)

- make sure the `DocumentPatchBuilder` `setNamespaces` with the correct `NamespaceContext`.

5. For batch data operation, the performant approach is MarkLogic Data Movement: instantiate the `QueryBatcher` with the searched Uris, supply the replace value or data fragment `PatchBuilder.replaceValue`
   , and complete the batch with
   `dbClient.newXMLDocumentManager().patch(uri, patchHandle);`

> MarkLogic Data Services: If you succeed above, perhaps, then go at a more robust and scalable enterprise SOA approach, please review [Data Services](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices).

- The implementation with Gradle is like:

[image: Data Services Implementations]

(Note, all of the transformation metrics should be parameters, including path/element/property name, namespace, value…etc. Nothing is hardcoded.) One proxy service declared in `service.json` can serve multiple end points (under `/root/df-ds/fxd` ) with different types of modules which give you the free rein to develop pure Java or extend the development platform to handle complex data operations.

> If these operations are persistent node update, you should consider in-memory node transform before the ingestion. Besides the MarkLogic data transformation tools, you can harness the power of XSLT2+.

> Saxon `XPathFactory` could be a serviceable vehicle to query/transform node. Not sure if it is a reciprocity, ML Java API implements the XPath `compile` to split large paths and stream transaction. XSLT/Saxon is not my forte; therefore, I can’t comment how comparable it is with this encode/decode particularity or how it handles transaction (insert, update…etc) streaming.

Comment: Ms. Fiona: The answer is rather substantial and the Query options correctly replace the node through parameter. THANK YOU! I am not satisfied with my original design now, so I need time to study the complex information.

Comment: Excellent notion. I never met anyone who could be satisfied when he knows he isn’t doing everything he should be doing…